# Why im receveing error when I press search twice in datagridview1?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have this code and seems to be working fine I think, when I write the code and press enter to search at txt_searchProduct_barcode, insert in datagridview1 and show all the product info at columns everything ok so far but when I search again to calculate the quatity and the total...in the last column its always giving the result of the zero in the price column and also last column at datagridview1 here is the sub code...

```
    Dim exist As Boolean = False, numrow As Integer = 0, numtext As Integer
    For Each itm As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If itm.Cells(0).Value IsNot Nothing Then
            If itm.Cells(1).Value.ToString = txt_searchProduct_barcode.Text Then
                exist = True
                numrow = itm.Index
                numtext = CInt(itm.Cells(8).Value)
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
    If exist = False Then
        Try
            conn.Open()
            cmd = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `tblproduct` WHERE `procode`='" & txt_searchProduct_barcode.Text & "'", conn)
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
            While dr.Read()
                If txt_searchProduct_barcode.Text = String.Empty Then
                    Return
                Else
                    'Create new row.
                    ' `procode`, `proname` , `progroup` , `uom` , `location` , `price` , `tax` , `totalprice`
                    Dim procode As String = dr("procode")
                    Dim Proname As String = dr("proname")
                    Dim Progroup As String = dr("progroup")
                    Dim uom As String = dr("uom")
                    Dim Price As Decimal = dr("price")
                    Dim tax As Decimal = dr("tax")
                    Dim totalprice As Decimal = dr("totalprice")

                    Dim totalqtyprice As Double

                    totalqtyprice = Price * tax / 100 + Price

                    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(DataGridView1.Rows.Count + 1, procode, Proname, Progroup, uom, Price, tax, totalprice, 1, totalqtyprice)


                End If
            End While
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            conn.Close()
        End Try
    Else
        DataGridView1.Rows(numrow).Cells(8).Value = CInt("1") + numtext
        DataGridView1.Rows(numrow).Cells(9).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(numrow).Cells(7).Value * DataGridView1.Rows(numrow).Cells(8).Value
    End If
End Sub
```

I want to understand where is the error and how to change. thanks

Comment: Please don't submit your question if the preview shows that the formatting is a mess. If you'd like us to take the time to help you, the least you can do is take the time to make your question readable.

Comment: Also, what has this question got to do with phpmyadmin? Please don't add irrelevant tags.

Comment: Sorry my bad, make my question readable.

Comment: As for the issue, you need to debug your code. If you don't know how, stop what you're doing learn now because it's something you need to do before posting here. Set a breakpoint and step through the code line by line to see exactly how it behaves and how that differs from your expectations. You're a developer, not a user, so you're not limited to the things that a user can do. You have development tools at your disposal. You need to use them.

Comment: Your code makes little sense as it is anyway. You execute your query and read the first row of results, then you check whether the search box was empty and exit if it is. Surely you'd be checking the search box before doing the search.

Comment: You will have to find out what `dr("price")` actually returns, as it is probably 0. Check the query results, and if it isn't 0, then you'll have to find out the value while debugging. Maybe you actually want to use `totalprice` instead of `price`? Also, why is `totalqtyprice` a `double` instead of `decimal` like the other numbers?